# Issue creating alert on vm for azure using guest metrics

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-alerts

Has anybody an idea what is going wrong. The monitoring guest metrics on Azure vm works and is running, just when I try making an alert straight out of the metric monitoring graph it keeps throwing this error. Guest diagnostics is enabled and I see the metrics.

> Creating alert rule Failed to create alert rule Webserver Free Disk
> Space. {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Detect invalid value:
> microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/guest for query parameter:
> 'metricnamespace', the value must be:
> Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines if the query parameter is provided,
> you can also skip this optional query parameter."}

Comment: Could please give some more insights for which guest metric you are trying to create the alert & also are you trying to create the alert from the portal ? Is this an Windows or Linux VM ?

Comment: The vm is a Linux VM for which I try to create the alert via the portal. I go to the monitoring, metrics using guest metrics and selecting free space percentage for a graph which works. Than I try to create the alert.

Comment: To be precise: Metric Namespace: Guest(classic)  Metric: Filesystem % free space

Comment: In our subscription, we have created a linux vm's with Ubuntu 18.04LTS & Ubuntu 20.04LTS images for both the vm's under monitoring section we are not able to see the enable [classic monitoring](https://i.imgur.com/CFRx6kW.png). While we are trying to create a alert for the above signal  `Guest(classic) Metric: Filesystem % free space` we are not able to find the particular metric even after enabling the guest metrics on the machine as shown in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/Mrv2MRX.png).

Comment: Could you please help us with some insight which flavor of Linux image(Ubuntu ,Centos, Redhat) that you are using & also with image name  that is running on that VM

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS